# Hide windows 7 partition from Ubuntu 12.04 USB

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-12.04

I am so hopelessly tired of following posts on all forums regarding my issue. I only want my windows 7 partition to be invisible from my Ubuntu 12.04 which I install and run from a USB flash drive. I tried all those fstab posts and nothing works. Everything needs so many commands. Can someone help me to do this task ?

Thanks a billion.

Comment: Please summarize what you have tried (so that we understand what is considered unacceptable to you).

Comment: What commands have you tried **exactly**?

Answer (score 0):

Read this post http://www.worldofnubcraft.com/969/hide-your-disks-or-partitions-from-nautilus/
So if you want to hide all your NTFS partition, or only the one with Windows installation I think you will do it.

There is also tool called "Disks", so you can try it also.

Or, if you knwo what is your partition for example dev/sda1 try this, also

```
/dev/sda1  /mnt/hidden  ntfs-3g  noauto,ro  0 0
```

also read this

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu

Comment: What do you mean by try this "/dev/sda1  /mnt/hidden  ntfs-3g  noauto,ro  0 0" Where am i supposed to  type all that ?

Comment: Terminal, CLI ??

Comment: @Deen You should add it to /etc/fstab and restart your sytem